# NFC Card Reader Android App with ACR122U as external reader

Tags: android, nfc

are there any apps in **2024** that can read a simple uid from a nfc card and work as  a keyboard on an android tablet (using A8 from Samsung) right now.
I've connected the ACR122U with OTG to the tablet an the only app that seems to work with that is mmtools. I want to use this for a login on a webapp and the reader should only work as a keyboard on any android device put the uid from the card in the webform and afterwards send  so that the form is submitted...
All apps I've found so far aren't working or are much too old and hardware like this one https://www.shopnfc.com/en/nfc-readers-writers/61-nfc-loginer.html are out of production.

Thank you!